# Prove $\{x \in \mathbb R : f(x) \neq g(x)\}$ is a null set $\iff$ $f(x)=g(x) \ \forall \ x \in \mathbb R$ for continuous functions $f,g$ in m.s.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B (\mathbb R), \lambda)$ be a measure space.

$\lambda$ denote the **Lebesgue-measure**.

Suppose $f,g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ are two continuous functions.

I want to prove the bi-implication $\{x \in \mathbb R : f(x) \neq g(x)\}$ is a null set $\iff$ $f(x)=g(x) \ \forall \ x \in \mathbb R$.

The direction $\Leftarrow$ is easy to prove. However $\Rightarrow$ is much harder. I've tried using the definition of continuity and using proof by contradiction, but without luck.

Comment: I think the measure has some more properties.
if you take a measure that is zero in an interval, then your statement does not hold..

Comment: For a simple counterexample, just take $\lambda$ as a point mass.

Comment: Sorry, I did't thought of specifying $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that continuity of $f$ and $g$ implies continuity of function $h$ prescribed by $x\mapsto\left|f\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right)\right|$. If the RHS
is not true then $h\left(x_{0}\right)>0$ for some $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$
and from the continuity of $h$ it follows that some $\epsilon>0$
exists with $h\left(x\right)>0$ for $x\in\left(x_{0}-\epsilon,x_{0}+\epsilon\right)$.

Then $\left(x_{0}-\epsilon,x_{0}+\epsilon\right)\subseteq\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f\left(x\right)\neq g\left(x\right)\right\} $
so that $\lambda\left(\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f\left(x\right)\neq g\left(x\right)\right\} \right)\geq2\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Thank you @drhab. Exactly the same thing I'd come to before checking this post again.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try to show that if $f$ is continuous and $x\in\mathbb R$ is such that $f(x)>0$, then there is $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $y\in[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon], f(y)>0$. Once you have this the conclusion is not far.

Comment: Aren't you assuming the measure is Lebesgue's?

Comment: The measure is indeed the Lebesgue measure :)

Answer (score 1):

Sets of full measure are dense (if not the complement contains an interval, so has non zero measure), so you have two continuous functions agreeing on a  dense set, which implies they are the same using sequential continuity.